# flutter - can't call a method in another file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have create a dart file with the method below. As you can see its job is to delete a file in Firestore. What I do not understand is why I can't call it from an other dart file. In the view where I want to use that I have imported 'import 'package:xxxxx/Services/Firestore/api_delete_file_in_firestore.dart';'

I am getting this error message: The method '_deleteFileInFireStore' isn't defined for the type '_Reference_Detail_Edit_SaveState'.

Thank you for your help.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class FireStore_Api{

  static void _deleteFileInFireStore(String fileToDelete) async {
    try {
      Reference firebaseStorageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileToDelete);
      await firebaseStorageRef.delete();
      print('Successfully deleted $fileToDelete storage item' );
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

now, this is where I am calling this function. I do not understand what is the problem.

```
 Padding(

                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:25.0),
                    child: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      //delete a record and the card displaying this record
                      // Delete the selected file

                      setState(() {
                        if (task_Attachments.length !=0) {
                          print ('delete' + result);

                          _deleteFileInFireStore(result); //delete the file selected in firestore
                          
                          task_Attachments.removeAt(j);
                          _delete(context);
                          
                        };
                      });
                    },
                      icon:Icon (Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,),),
                  ):
```

Comment: Try to declare your function like  **deleteFileInFireStore** not **static void _deleteFileInFireStore** hope it help

Comment: I have done that, but I am still getting the same error message.
The method 'deleteFileInFireStore' isn't defined for the type '_Reference_Detail_Edit_SaveState'.
I am writing this function in another page, because I will need it several times. I just do not want to write it locally each time.

Comment: If you declare this function inside FireStore_Api class so declare like **FireStore_Api().deleteFileInFireStore**   or this function no need to declare inside FireStore_Api  class

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks. No more error message. This is great. Have a lovely day.

Comment: Be aware that every method with naming start with `_` is private. It can't be accessed outside its file.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong with your function, the function you created is **private**, **and private functions can only be accessed within the file in which it was created**.

Remove the **_** underscore from the function: **_deleteFileInFireStore(String fileToDelete)**

Final result

> **deleteFileInFireStore(String fileToDelete)**

Answer (score 0):

In the file you want to access, you can first create an object for this class and try to access it through that object. (I know you define static but I don't understand what's the problem and this will help for solution)